# Generating Differential file package in TFS 2008

Tags: tfs

I want to generate a package file to update an application automatically. I have changeset and label of the last update from the TFS 2008.
How do I generate a differential package from the last update to the current version?
Can I automate this? TFS can automatically generate a package with all the modified and added files?

PS.: It´s a ASP.Net MVC3 application

Comment: You say you want to update an application, but you don't update the source files that have changed: you have to update the assemblies that those components compile into.  What kind of project are you working with?

Comment: It´s a ASP.Net MVC application. In update package must have JPG, GIF, HTML, JS and the assemblies.